# Javascript type conversion

Tags: javascript, firefox, xpcom

I'm writting a Firefox extension. Using javascript, I want to download a binary file from a web POST, and then I want write its contents into a file. My difficulty is how to convert from the type returned by the web to the type needed to write:

```
var c=new XMLHttpRequest();
c.responseType = "arraybuffer";
var data=Uint8Array(c.response);
```

"data" contains the binary contents.
To write it to a file:

```
var file= FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["somefile"]);
var ostm= FileUtils.openFileOutputStream(file);
var bstm= Cc['@mozilla.org/binaryoutputstream;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIBinaryOutputStream);
bstm.setOutputStream(ostm);
```

Then I need to write "data" in the "bstm", but the only way I have found to do it is very slow:

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
  bstm.write8(data[i]);
```

This works, but it's very slow for medium size files.
Is there a better way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what your trying to achieve here, but maybe this can help you out.

Poster extension for Firefox: http://www.google.nl/codesearch#1Ekgj8MZCE0/README&q=Firefox%20extension&l=9&ct=rc&cd=6

It seems to be doing what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a "conventional" array like this:

```
var dataArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(data);
```

This will allow you to write out that data:

```
bstm.writeByteArray(dataArray, dataArray.length);
```

Supposedly, this conversion [will become unnecessary in Firefox 11](http://bholley.wordpress.com/2011/12/13/typed-arrays-supported-in-xpconnect/), you will be able to pass in `Uint8Array` directly.